# What toolkit does JIRA use for the basic search filters?

Tags: javascript, gui-toolkit

JIRA has a nice search tool built into the issue tracker -- date-pickers, multi-select label pickers, number filters (min/max), and the like. For the label filter specifically, I'm wondering if this is a feature that Atlassian home-rolled; or did they use a plug-and-play framework that I too can add to my site; or something in between? I realize there's some back-end stuff that needs to happen in order to populate the list, but the UI element itself looks really slick.

The image below, from [jira.atlassian.com](https://jira.atlassian.com/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CONF), shows the label filter I'm interested in.

[image: jira search filters]

I tried pulling apart the source on the page, but I only found things that appear to be unrelated: AUI (Atlassian's UI standards?) and AJS (a low-level jQuery-esque library?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this plugin is the one you need. But you still will need to do the backend magic to ensure it works.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Looks like a great tool. Do you know if it's the one that JIRA uses (and how do you know)?

Comment: I don't think this is the one Jira uses. Jira is using handlebars on his templates so I assumen he should be using something like backbone/ember to provide functionality to his dropdowns. But the chosenjs will provide you with a fast way to create the smoth selectors with the searchbox. If your are planning something bigger, you will have to do the hard work. I suggest you to use ReactJS to encapsulate components and keep an easy track of the functionalities.